# WPF cannot set Build Action for added file

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017, buildaction

my app is WPF (VS 2017). I want to add an image to the project and I need to use a relative path, in order to have that included in the app when it is published. (There was a similar question here and I would be happy if the answers would work for me.)

The thing is that I cannot add an “existing item” when the folder to keep it resides further down in the solution explorer (past “Properties” and “Referencies”). Unlike in UWP, files like image files do not appear when browsing. On the other hand, when adding a folder right under the solution header in the solution explorer I can add an existing item. But the image file in my case then does not have any other properties than name and size, nothing to set there. But as I have learned from the answers I mentioned, “Build Action” must be set. And indeed, the source path is not recognized.

In the UWP, the properties of an image file show all these, like “Build Action” and so on. Seems to be a shy deer… Any idea what is wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The image file has to be added to a project, not the solution. In the "Add Existing Item" dialog, select the appropriate file type fllter, e.g. `*.*`. You may also create a folder in your project where you add the image files.

Comment: Ok, I did not select the file type. What I found for me shortly after my post is: copy and paste worked, but I wondered why it was different to UWP. May be the correct file type back then was already selected without my awareness. But thank you for pointing that out.